# How do I properly reference this pointer multiple times?

Tags: c++

This is my function to find the union of 2 set arrays located by a void pointer which I have issues running the first part to copy Set A into the union Set before doing comparisons with Set B

Right now the output of this code produces example
Set A = {1,5,7,8}
Union Set = {8,8,8,8} Copies last element of Set A 4 times
as the last loop causes the temp pointer to point at 8.
Do I have to create a new int pointer for each loop or is  there a better way of going around this

// Note I cannot use vectors or sorting methods as it isnt in my learning scope yet so i'll have to stick to the primitive comparison way

```
//Definitions
// VoidPtr is Void*
// aSet is (VoidPtr *a = new VoidPtr[MAX])
// getElementI(aSet[i]) Returns an integer value at that position of the pointer

void findUnion(VoidPtr * aSet,VoidPtr * bSet,VoidPtr * unionSet,int sizea,int sizeb,int &sizec)
{
    int* temp;
    VoidPtr vp;
    int notEqual = 0;

    // Copy set a into set c
    for(int i =0; i < sizea; i++)
        {
            *temp = getElementI(aSet[i]);
            vp = temp;
            unionSet[i] = vp;
        }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really look like c++ code, more like c.

Comment: What do you mean,can you give me examples?
Its supposedly a c++ module though

Comment: I wouldn't use any raw pointers in c++, but rather [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Comment: I'm not sure,maybe we're just going over the basics of pointers.So I'm just trying to use what's in my learning scope to avoid confusing myself.

Comment: Oh boy, _YAIT_ again :-P ...

Answer (score 0):

```
int* temp;
```

Here `temp` is an uninitiaised pointer

```
*temp = getElementI(aSet[i]);
```

Here `temp` is being dereferenced. Dereferencing uninitialised pointers results in a program crash (at best) and all sorts of weird behaviour (at worst).

I'm finding it quite hard to understand what you really need to do, but allocating a new int pointer every time round the loop sounds reasonable. Like this

```
for(int i =0; i < sizea; i++)
{
    int *temp = new int (getElementI(aSet[i]));
    unionSet[i] = temp;
}
```

But I am *guessing*.

Comment: So i guess i have to set it to int* temp = int new?

Comment: @johntod I expect that you need a new int *every* time round the loop, see edit.

Comment: That worked perfectly.
I'm trying to copy and paste set A into set C before comparing set C with set B to add missing elements to form the union set